# Ansible Unit Loop with Include and Register

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbooks:

```
# outer.yml
- name: wait for inner
  include: inner.yml
  retries: 60
  delay: 5
  until: inner_result.content=="true"
  with_items: "{{ stuff | default([]) }}"

# inner.yml
- name: check to see if {{ item.name }} is ready
  uri:
      url: "http://localhost/someurl/{{ item.name }}/ready/"
      return_content: true
  register: inner_result
```

Outer executes inner properly, and it executes it for every element of the stuff array. However, the until requirement does not work. The task completes even though inner_result.content=="false".

Doing away with the include, the following does work fine:

```
# outer.yml
- name: wait for stuff to be ready
  uri:
       url: "http://localhost/someurl/{{ item.name }}/ready/"
       return_content: true
  register: inner_result
  retries: 60
  delay: 5
  until: inner_result.content=="true"
  with_items: "{{ stuff | default([]) }}"
```

However, I'd really like to get the include version to work, as I'd like to include more actions inside the loop. Am I doing something wrong, or does Ansible not support using until with register variables defined inside an include?

I'm using version 2.1.0.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you call `include`, Ansible actually places tasks from included file into execution queue after the current task.
In your example `wait for inner` loop generates a long list of tasks for each item from `with_items`and exits.
Then this long list of appended tasks executed one by one.

If you need some heavy checking, I suggest writing your own module for this task.